# How to get current user who's accessing an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

To get the current logged in user at the system I use this code:

```
string opl = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

I work on an ASP.NET application where I need this information. So I've put my application on a server and tried the code above, and I get "Network Service" in the string opl. I need to know the current user of the PC who accesses my ASP.NET application.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563703/get-windows-logged-in-username-asp-net.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using membership you can do: `Membership.GetUser()`

Your code is returning the Windows account which is assigned with ASP.NET.

Additional Info Edit:
You will want to include System.Web.Security

```
using System.Web.Security
```

Comment: in which namespace can I find this?

Comment: System.Web.Security namespace

Comment: I'm getting: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."-error

Comment: do you use membership feature of ASP .NET? which mode of authentication do you use?

Comment: Windows Authentication, how can I decide which feature to use?

Comment: you use windows auth. when you want to treat users of your page as windows users (active directory) stored on your server. If you want to maintain users in database separate from windows users you should use forms auth.

Comment: @Robert What if I'm using Asp .Net core 2.1 and I want to get the user logged on in Ubuntu? Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 60):

The quick answer is `User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User`

Ensure your web.config has the following authentication element.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Further Reading**: [Recipe: Enabling Windows Authentication within an Intranet ASP.NET Web application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application)

Comment: This if you're looking for the user login. Specifically the string is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Now it returns nothing the string is empty :s

Comment: Read the article, you need to configure windows authentication.

Comment: I've read the article, windows authentication is set by default

Comment: Do you have IIS configured correctly? Are you in an intranet scenario where the credentials can be "flowed" to the server. Windows authentication doesn't work over the wider Internet

Comment: Take a look at this related question, you could try some of the suggestions from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215000/httpcontext-current-user-not-populated-with-windows-authentication-enabled

Comment: If anonymous authentication is also enabled then it is used instead of Windows authentication.

Answer (score 25):

Using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` should work. 
Please check the IIS Site settings on the server that is hosting your site by doing the following:

1. Go to IIS → *Sites* → Your Site → *Authentication*

   [image: IIS Settings]
2. Now check that *Anonymous Access* is Disabled & *Windows Authentication* is Enabled.

   [image: Authentication]
3. Now `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` should return something like this:

   `domain\username`

Answer (score 11):

The best practice is to check the `Identity.IsAuthenticated` Property first and then get the `usr.UserName` like this:

```cs
string userName = string.Empty;

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null && 
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    System.Web.Security.MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();
    if (usr != null)
    {  
        userName = usr.UserName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use a property of the page. And the interesting thing is that you can access that property anywhere in your code.

Use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't look too far.

If you develop with ASP.NET MVC, you simply have the user as a [property of the `Controller` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx). So in case you get lost in some models looking for the current user, try to step back and to get the relevant information in the controller.

In the controller, just use:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

  ...

  var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
  ...
```

with `userId` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus answer above seems to have have a compatibility issue with CORS support. In order to use the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name attribute you must disable anonymous authentication in order to force Windows authentication to provide the authenticated user information. Unfortunately, I believe you must have anonymous authentication enabled in order to process the pre-flight OPTIONS request in a CORS scenario.

You can get around this by leaving anonymous authentication enabled and using the HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity attribute instead. This will return the authenticated user information (assuming you are in an intranet scenario) even with anonymous authentication enabled. The attribute returns a WindowsUser data structure and both are defined in the System.Web namespace

```
        using System.Web;
        WindowsIdentity user;
        user  = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same issue.

This is what worked for me:

[image: Setting up Authentication in IIS Panel]

[image: Setting up Properties of Windows Authentication in IIS]

Setting up Properties of Windows Authentication in IIS
[image: NTLM has to be the topmost]

NTLM has to be the topmost.
Further Web.config modifications, make sure you already have or add if these do not exist:

```
<system.web>

  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <identity impersonate="true"/>

</system.web>

 <!-- you need the following lines of code to bypass errors, concerning type of Application Pool (integrated pipeline or classic) -->

<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

See below a legit explanation for the two nodes  and

[Difference between <system.web> and <system.webServer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355261/difference-between-system-web-and-system-webserver)

And, of course , you get the username by

```
//I am using the following to get the index of the separator "\\" and remove the Domain name from the string
int indexOfSlashChar = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\"); 

loggedInWindowsUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(indexOfSlashChar + 1);
```