# What is the best way to identify logged user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was looking for the efficient way to track the logged users when using `asp.net` `login control`

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Membership.GetUser() != null)
            {
                var user = Membership.GetUser();
                Session["user"] = user;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["user"] = "";
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why all this pain and why do you try to save it in the Session (which is user specific and not application specific), when you can simply get it from this object:

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

check this one for details: [How to get current user who's accessing an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417125/how-to-get-current-user-whos-accessing-asp-net-app)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the user identity (if you're using asp.net forms membership) through:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

On logging in, if the user is valid, use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, false);
```

rather than relying on Session to store user logged in state.

You can then check if a user is logged in by:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

And get their username doing:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply use

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `User.Identity.Name`

Please have a look at [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)