# Getting The Current User Name In ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running a webpage that needs to be able to read the login id of the current user.  Here is the code I am using:

```
string id = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Currently this returns the correct login but when I use it in this method:

```
protected Boolean isPageOwner()
{
    string id = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    alert("User: " + id);
    if (id.Equals(pageOwnerID))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (accessPermission.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the method returns false even though the id returned is identical to pageOwnerID.  I'm really not sure which part of this I am having a problem with.

On a side note, my login id is of the form string1/string2 but the code retrieves it as string1 + string2 without the slash.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What is the exact string for `id` and `pageOwnerID`. It sounds like it may be `abc/123` and `abc123` from your description, which would not work.

Comment: When I was developing this page on my local machine I was able to detect my logon id in the form "abc/123" with the slash.  As soon as I deployed the page on the server the logon id was retrieved without the slash -- so abc123.  So I changed pageOwnerID to remove the slash but the test for equality is failing mysteriously.

Comment: Why don't you log/output both `id` and `pageOwnerID` so you can compare. Obviously they are not the same.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a backslash, \?

Comment: Suddenly the code is retrieving "NT AUTHORITYNETWORK SERVICE" as the user name.  So now I have a new problem.

Comment: Do not use the WinIdentity, use Request.User

Comment: I can't find an example of Request.User -- could you show me the whole command?

Comment: See answer below for an example on using `Request.User` -> `HttpContext.Current.User`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Current User who's accessing ASP.net app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417125/how-to-get-current-user-whos-accessing-asp-net-app)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using this to retrieve the username....

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

It sounds like windows authentication is not being used - you need to disable anonymous access and enable windows integrated security.

Add this to your web.config...

```xml
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/> 
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This would work under normal circumstances, but IIS configuration may setup impersonation that will fool ASP.NET into thinking System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name (or Request.User.Identity.Name) is not the actual logged in user.

Comment: It will be empty if `IsAuthenticated` is false.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant I had tried `string id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` without the if-clause.  Also, this is in my web.config file: `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Comment: You need to configure IIS to enable integrated security and disable anonymous.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll pounce on the server admin first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the current logged in user's identity from within any layer (or Project in your solution) then use:

`string userId = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId();`