# asp.net: how to get the server to recognize user's user ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i was working on an xp machine and had installed IIS on the xp machine. without a problem i was getting the users identity like this:

```
 string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

we just upgraded to windows 7 and are using IIS 7.

executing that same line in the compiler works fine; however, when i try to execute that line from IIS here is the username that is returned:

```
IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

how can i get it to return the actual user name of the person who is logged onto his computer and looking at this web application?

please keep in mind that it uses windows authentication and works only on our company network

Comment: What do you mean 'execute that line from IIS'? You mean when you deploy the site to the server?

Comment: @Shredder yes my friend exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the current user has authenticated? Is windows authentication actually working? This should be the current user's id if and only if they have authenticated.

Note some common issues here, specifically the order here with windows auth vs. anonymous

[HttpContext.Current.User not populated with Windows Authentication enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215000/httpcontext-current-user-not-populated-with-windows-authentication-enabled)

Also what does HttpContext.User.Identity.Name return for you?